# Jupyter command `jupyter-serverextension` not found

Tags: jupyter

I am trying to connect jupyter to google colabs via WebSocket extension on jupyter. but whenever i try to add it via command line. it gives me errors. can anyone help me out?

```
pip install jupyter_http_over_ws

jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws

usage: jupyter [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir] [--paths] [--json] [--debug] [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
  subcommand     the subcommand to launch

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version      show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
  --config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
  --data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
  --runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
  --paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable format.
  --json         output paths as machine-readable json
  --debug        output debug information about paths

Available subcommands: console contrib dejavu events execute kernel kernelspec lab labextension labhub migrate nbclassic nbconvert nbextensions_configurator notebook qtconsole run server troubleshoot trust

Jupyter command `jupyter-serverextension` not found.
```

I tried to install this extension with this command line but nothing has changed:

```
pip3 install install jupyter_http_over_ws
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead use the following line:

```
> jupyter server extension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws
```

You will get a warning of deprecated command but it works.This worked for me.